# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, casting

I have got a class like this.

```
 public static SkillViewModel GetAllList(string ID)
{
    ListViewModel viewModel = new ListViewModel();
    DataTable dt = DAL.GetAllList(ID);

    List<Skill> skills = new List<Skill>();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        Skill skill = new Skill() { GroupName = row["GroupName"] != null ? row["GroupName"].ToString() : string.Empty, SubName = row["SubName"] != null ? row["SubName"].ToString() : string.Empty};
        skills.Add(skill);
    }
    viewModel.skills = skills;
    viewModel.skills = skills.GroupBy(x => x.GroupName);  //Showing error in this line
   return viewModel;

}
```

and another one like this :

```
 public class SkillViewModel
  {
    public List<Skill> skills { get; set; }
  }

  public class Skill
{
    [DisplayName("Sub Name")]
    [Required]
    public string SubName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Group Name")]
    [Required]
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
}
```

But it is failing it by saying

> *Error: Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>'
>   to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)*

Please Help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add `ToList` with `SelectMany` at the end of the statement like:

```
viewModel.skills = skills.GroupBy(x => x.GroupName).SelectMany(r => r).ToList();
```

using `SelectMany` would flatten the group, not really sure why you are grouping your data, whereas your property is `List<Skill>`

Comment: I think that were both wrong in this case, `ToList` will return a `List<IGrouping<T>>` not `ListT>`

Comment: @LukeHennerley, yes, just modified my answer with `SelectMany`, but that would just flatten the grouped items

Comment: I suspect it is just bad design in the `ViewModel`, it seems as though the OP wants a group to be assigned but the property isn't reflecting that

Comment: @Habib, Thanks for your help.
The List<Skill> gives me a list of items as GroupName and SubName. But I need to group the SubNames on basis of this GroupName. So was using it. Please also see this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933149/sorting-table-by-its-groupname-where-data-is-fetched-from-database-using-mvc-2

Comment: Thanks that was of great help.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Skills` property is a `List<T>`.

You need to call `.ToList()` when you are assigning the property.

When you call `GroupBy` you will no longer have `T` instead you will have `IGrouping<T>`. This means that you either need to filter your group and get a `List<T>` back out or change your skills type to be:

```
public List<IGrouping<Skill>> skills { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks that was of great help.